# Android kSOAP handling "302 Status"

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am trying to access a webservice from kSOAP, the service is sending `"302 Status"` with a new URL location. However my call throws exception. Here is the call:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, null);
```

The exception I get is :

`org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44fcd058)`

If the replace the original URL with the redirected one, the code above works fine. If I can read the status I can handle it well but the problem is I am getting exception which does not seem relevant.

Please suggest me some ways to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

The kSOAP library tries to parse the response from the server as xml. In this case the response is not a xml object like it expects. If you debug it, you will notice that you receive a HTML page. Unfortunately I can't help you because I'm facing the same problem.